# Convergence of infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}$ converges to 1.

Comment: Can you see this paper https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1988-22.pdf page no. 105, para two, irrationality sequence

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B(n%2B2)n!%7D) suggests that there is some telescoping going on..

Answer (score 5):

Try to use
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}=\frac{(n+1)}{(n+2)!}=\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}
\end{align}

Comment: @user157835 No, it is $(e-2)-(e-\frac{5}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$. I think the sum should starts at $n=0$ to get 1.

Comment: oh..got it thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Write $u(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}$. Then $$u'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!} = x(e^x - 1) = xe^x - x,$$ so integration by parts yields $u(x) = e^x(x-1) - \frac{x^2}{2} + C$. Since $u(0) = 0$, $C = 1$, from which we can conclude $u(1) = 1/2$. If you start your sum at $n = 0$ instead of $n = 1$, you'll instead get a result of $1.$